# Ensemble Probabilities of the different models

Tags: random-forest, probability, ensemble-modeling

I have a **Multiclass Dataset** and I am getting probabilities of classes from RandomForest.

However, I want to divide the dataset for each class as examples of either the case belongs to that class or not(Binary Classification). I want to know , when I get the prediction of those models for a yes or no.

How can I ensemble them in such a way that **Overall** Sum of probabilities as one?

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be done by using this command at the time of prediction, giving example in R

```
#To predict with probabilities
testSet$pred_rf_prob<-`predict(object,model_rf,testSet[,predictors],type='prob')`
```

To take average of the predictions:

```
testSet$pred_avg<-(testSet$pred_rf_prob$Y+testSet$pred_knn_prob$Y+testSet$pred_lr_prob$Y)/3
```

This [Link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/02/introduction-to-ensembling-along-with-implementation-in-r/) , might be helpful. Do have a look.

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Don't know about R. Working in python. Can you help me in that?

Comment: sure will have a look and update you in sometime.

Comment: Do go through this [Link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html), here you have something called as **Probability**, `clf3 = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)`. I think that might work, have a look but i'm not sure.

Comment: @Toros91 It seems to me you are missing the essential part of OP's question which relates to handling probabilities out of a series of 1-vs-1 models defined from an original 1-vs-all problem setting.

Comment: yes, i understood that part, try giving Probabilities to False and see how it works.